# Can I host a SPA React app with firebase without cloud functions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I have the intention to deploy a small react single page app for educational purposes and wanted to test something new. Firebase seems like a good option especially because it offers free tier. However there is something that is bothering me, the free tier's  cloud functions only support node.js 8 which is obsolete . I plan to use the NoSQL database and hosting options offered by firebase. Correct me if I am wrong but if the CRUD operations are made by a react hooks there is no node.js involvement and therefore no cloud functions are needed? Basically the CRUD is done by the user's browser because he runs the react app .js files and this means that I can safely use the free tier?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just performing queries directly to Firestore or Realtime database from your web app code, then you don't need Cloud Functions at all, and do not need to enable billing on your project.  This is should be easy to try for yourself - simply follow the instructions in the documentation for the database you've chosen.